# Fastest Way to Filter on Multiple Predicates in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I am doing a lengthy filter quite often and would like to know if there is any difference in performance between the following methods, or if they are just a matter of style?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@""];
NSPredicate *blockPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:nil];
NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[]];
```

I did find another post mentioning they were a matter of style, but it did not discuss `predicateWithBlock` or go into any detail of how these methods work.

I have another question that is semi-related: is it faster to in-line the predicates passed into an NSCompoundPredicate, or is it the same speed as declaring them outside as variables and passing the variables in? i.e.

```
NSCompoundPredicate *cp = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
@[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:""], [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:""]];
```

or

```
NSCompoundPredicate *cp = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
@[pred1, pred2]];
```

Any explanation on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Can you confirm that you are talking about in-memory filtering? Core Data filtering would of course not work with blocks, but just to make sure...

Comment: @jcaron Yes I'm talking about in-memory filtering; I'm not using Core Data